# How to copy data from MySQL database table and use it to update another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have searched the internet, I couldn't find any example or tutorial on that. I want to select data from a table's column A, and use it to update all the data in another table's column B. The two table have equal numbers of rows, and the same foreign key. Please, how can I do that?

Comment: What have you searched? What research have you done? This way people who want to answer can tell how much you understand and what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query, change the field names as per your table structure

```
UPDATE table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.common_field = table1.common_field
SET table2.value = table1.value
```

OR

```
UPDATE table2  
SET table2.value = (  
SELECT table1.value  
    FROM table1  
    WHERE table1.common_field = table2.common_field LIMIT 0, 1 
)
```

The second query will fail without `Limit` if there are multiple entries.

Comment: Let me try that right away.